# How to properly pass a Win32 class object to a function

Tags: function, powershell, winapi

I try to write script (PowerShell) that return CPU name using Win32:

```
$temp = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor

$temp.Name

function Get-CPU-Name {
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$Temp1
    return $Temp1.Name
}

Get-CPU-Name
```

A function call should return the name of the processor, but it does not return anything. How to correctly pass a variable with the results of the "Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor" command to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but forgot to put the parameter inside `param(..)`.

This should work:

```
function Get-CPU-Name { 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$Temp1
    )
    $Temp1.Name
}

Get-CPU-Name (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor)
```

Comment: $Value = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ErrorAction Stop

function Get-CPU-Name { 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)][System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$Temp1
    )
    return ($Temp1.Name)
}

Get-CPU-Name -Temp1 $Value

Comment: Good catch, Theo. @Blademoon: It's tricky that forgetting `param(...)` is _quietly ignored_ - I've asked if changing that is possible in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10614)

Comment: Who can answer how to check such a transmitted parameter for emptiness? To protect the function from possible errors?

Comment: Why not just use `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Name`?

Comment: @Blademoon: `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]`, as in your original attempt, will enforce non-emptiness - as long as it is properly inside a `param(...)` block.